# Prevent node to join a channel if provided unknown certificate

Tags: jgroups

I'm creating a JGroups cluster where nodes have to identify with certificates before they get the secret key and can join a cluster.
So the protocol stack looks like following:

```
static final Protocol[] PROTOCOL_STACK = {
            new TCP()
                    .setValue("bind_port", 7800)
                    .setValue("max_bundle_size", 64000)
                    .setValue("sock_conn_timeout", 300)
                    .setValue("thread_pool_min_threads", 0)
                    .setValue("thread_pool_max_threads", 20)
                    .setValue("thread_pool_keep_alive_time", 3000),
            new TCPPING()
                    .setValue("async_discovery", false)
                    .setValue("initial_hosts",(getClusteringInitialIps())) 
                    .setValue("port_range", 0)
                    .setValue("send_cache_on_join", true)
                    .setValue("return_entire_cache", true),
            new SSL_KEY_EXCHANGE()
                    .setValue("keystore_name", "/tmp/clustercert.jks")
                    .setValue("keystore_password", "my_password"),
            new ASYM_ENCRYPT()
                    .setValue("use_external_key_exchange", true)
                    .setValue("encrypt_entire_message", true)
                    .setValue("sym_keylength", 256)
                    .setValue("sym_algorithm", "AES")
                    .setValue("asym_keylength", 512)
                    .setValue("asym_algorithm", "RSA"),
            new MERGE3()
                    .setValue("min_interval", 10000)
                    .setValue("max_interval", 30000),
            new FD_SOCK(),
            new FD()
                    .setValue("timeout", 3000)
                    .setValue("max_tries", 3),
            new VERIFY_SUSPECT()
                    .setValue("timeout", 1500),
            new BARRIER(),
            new NAKACK2()
                    .setValue("use_mcast_xmit", false)
                    .setValue("discard_delivered_msgs", true),
            new UNICAST3(),
            new STABLE()
                    .setValue("desired_avg_gossip", 50000)
                    .setValue("max_bytes", 4000000),
            new GMS()
                    .setValue("print_local_addr", true)
                    .setValue("join_timeout", 2000),
            new FRAG3()
                    .setValue("frag_size", 60000),
            new STATE()
```

After starting the cluster, when a node with an unknown certificate tries to connect I get an expected exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

But though the connecting node didn't get the secret key from coordinator it is still able to join the channel.

I thought, that because the ASYM_ENCRYPT protocol is below the GMS protocol, nodes can't connect if they are not able to decrypt the message.
Is there an error in my protocol stack or why are nodes still able to join a channel?

**Edit:**
Just saw in the source code, that a node will always join a channel if not using `AUTH`. Even if it provides an unknown certificate. `ASYM_ENCRYPT#skip(msg)` prevents a message with `JOIN_REQ` header from being encrypted. Which means, even if `ASYM_ENCRYPT` is below `GMS` the message won't be encrypted and such the node can join the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this: with a correct certificate, I get this exception:
`4779 [ERROR] ASYM_ENCRYPT: A: failed creating secret key and initializing ciphers
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters`

When I change the `SSL_KEY_EXCHANGE` and `ASYM_ENCRYPT` protocols to the version shown below, everything works:

```
    new SSL_KEY_EXCHANGE()
        .setValue("keystore_name", "/home/bela/certs/FR59235.jks")
        .setValue("keystore_password", "FR59235"),
      new ASYM_ENCRYPT()
        .setValue("use_external_key_exchange", true)
        .setValue("encrypt_entire_message", true)
        .setValue("sym_keylength", 128)
        .setValue("sym_algorithm", "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
        .setValue("asym_keylength", 512)
        .setValue("asym_algorithm", "RSA"),
```

Comment: With "everything works" do you mean, that a node can't join the channel with an unknown certificate?

Comment: No, it shoud be able to join but won't get any messages as it can't decrypt them